# Getting a minimum number of results from fulltext search

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a text field that I'm searching against using an array of keywords and right now, I'm either searching for all of the keywords or any of the keywords.

My question is: is there a way to pull results with a minimum number of keywords?
For example, I'm searching for 6 keywords, but I only need 50% of them to match, so I want the fulltext search to only return results that have matched at least 3 of the keywords.

Is this even possible?
Maybe by using a FullText Modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a fulltext search using the [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) modifier in your select statement, it can display the number of matches in the search.
Example:

```
SELECT id, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('MySQL Fulltext' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS matches
FROM table_name
HAVING matches > 2;
```